# kohana_http_exception 404: The requested URL / was not found on this server. - Linux environment

Tags: linux, http-status-code-404, kohana, kohana-3.3

I am getting this error when I transfer my kohana project form windows to linux environment.

Kohana_HTTP_exception [404]: The requested URL / was not found on this server.

What could happen? .htaccess is working fine on master branch but when i shift to develop it send me 404 error. This is Kohana 3.3 by the way.

Answer (score 0):

I get it now! Linux environment is case sensitive. I have to rename my Model and Controller folders uppercased like:

application/classes/Controller/Login/Login.php

```
**class Controller_Login_Login extends Controller_Base {
```

application/classes/Model/User/Token.php

```
class Model_User_Token extends Model_Auth_User_Token {
```

Answer (score 0):

Check, is apache mod_rewrite enable and loaded at phpinfo();
In My case I've just enable mod_rewrite at apache.

```
 sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

and than restart

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Check .htaccess rules.

And note, that  Controllers names  are case sensitivity.